# fastest solution to "test" SCSS in a simple html page

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, atom-editor

I would like writing just few lines of SCSS, I would like testing it without losing my mind with configurations.. just a quick solution to convert SCSS to CSS.

Do you know any javascript libraries to do this in a simple html page (just for debugging, no release)? A plugin for Atom, Visual Studio or other editors?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On Vistual Studio I suggest `Live Sass Compiler`, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass,

I think it could be the "quickest solution" you are looking for.

Sometimes for quick tests I just use a snippet of code to try SCSS on my HTML, https://github.com/orsifrancesco/sillyScss